# How to bring back long C#.Net Coding line in a Single Line?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008

I am using Visual Studio 2008. I wrongly pressed some keys in the keyboard. So my C#.Net codings are broken into the next line.

If my coding line exceeds the monitor size then the remaining coding parts are displaying in the next line like this:

```
txtPOSubTotalAmt.Text = Convert.ToString((Convert.ToDecimal(POV)) + "Amount" + 
"/-";
```

How to display it in a single line?

Comment: Can you clarify - is there a carriage return there or is the single line displaying wrapped?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit -> Advanced -> Word Wrap.

Answer (score 3):

Use the menu option: Edit -> Advanced -> Word Wrap